# Remove old data (flush buffer) from Bokeh Plot fed with AjaxDataSource?

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to remove old data that is streamed in append mode when using AjaxDataSource?

Here's the code I'm running:

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import AjaxDataSource, CustomJS

# Bokeh related code

adapter = CustomJS(code="""
    const result = {x: [], y: []}
    const pts = cb_data.response.points
    for (i=0; i<pts.length; i++) {
        result.x.push(pts[i][0])
        result.y.push(pts[i][1])
    }
    return result
""")

source = AjaxDataSource(data_url='http://localhost:5050/data',
                        polling_interval=200, adapter=adapter, mode='append', max_size=20)

p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800, background_fill_color="lightgrey",
           title="Streaming Noisy sin(x) via Ajax")
p.circle('x', 'y', source=source)

p.x_range.follow = "end"
p.x_range.follow_interval = 10

# Flask related code

app = Flask(__name__)

def crossdomain(f):
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
        resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
        h = resp.headers
        h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, OPTIONS, POST"
        h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(21600)
        requested_headers = request.headers.get('Access-Control-Request-Headers')
        if requested_headers:
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = requested_headers
        return resp
    return wrapped_function

x = list(np.arange(0, 6, 0.1))
y = list(np.sin(x) + np.random.random(len(x)))

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'])
@crossdomain
def data():
    x.append(x[-1]+0.1)
    y.append(np.sin(x[-1])+np.random.random())
    return jsonify(points=list(zip(x,y)))

# show and run

show(p)
app.run(port=5050)
```

This is modified slightly from the example here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.3.2/examples/howto/ajax_source.py

I simply added `mode='append', max_size=20` on the line that creates the AjaxDataSource.

My issue is that I want to flush/reset the AjaxDataSource buffer occasionally. My use-case is plotting data over time. If I pause the data generation, I'm able to pause the AjaxDataSource no problem, but when I resume the plotting the graph jumps to the latest data point and keeps all of the old data. What I want to have happen is that I want the old data to be flushed from the AjaxDataSource internal buffer. I was trying to use the ResetTool functionality to accomplish this, however upon much reflection and soul-searching I don't believe this is the intended use of this function. So the question remains, how can I flush the internal buffer of AjaxDataSource?

Side Note: The other option for AjaxDataSource is non-append mode, in which case the entire graph is replaced with new dataset. I don't want to use this mode, as there is a lot of data and using append mode is MUCH more efficient from CPU/Memory perspective.

Comment: Did you try setting your source to: `source.data = {'x: [], 'y': []}` and then `source.change.emit()` ?

Comment: @Tony if I do that I get "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'change' If I remove the source.data = {} line then I get "AttributeError: 'AjaxDataSource' object has no attribute 'change' "
Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: `source` should be your `AjaxDataSource` and it is definitely not a `dict` so I don't get it. But you could also try `data = {'x: [], 'y': []}` and then `source.data = data` instead

Comment: That does work to replace the AjaxDataSource with empty values. But it doesn't replace what's already in the buffer. I tried the change function and I get: `AttributeError: 'AjaxDataSource' object has no attribute 'change'`

Comment: @tony, change is not a function of ColumnDataSource, which is what AjaxDataSource inherits.

Comment: It think it should be. Check [this page](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html) but maybe smth changed and it's now only available in JS. But doing it the other way using: `source.data = data` doesn't require `source.change.emit()` to be called.